# Oracle SQL - Query with timestamp - Slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that looks for all records for yesterday from a column with type: TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE.

The issue I'm facing is the query runs extremely slow, I'm wondering if there is something I'm doing incorrectly when querying with a timestamp format?

```
select * from inventory_transaction
WHERE Complete_timestamp >= to_timestamp(sysdate-1) 
and Complete_timestamp < to_timestamp(sysdate);
```

Comment: Don't use to_timestamp on date datatype - it's implicit datatype conversion. Just use `systimestamp-interval'1' day` or `cast(... as timestamp) `

Comment: why not use `systimestamp`? getting rid of the function call in the predicate will help, but it is more likely that you need an index on the complete_timestamp column and/or accurate table statistics for the cost-based optimizer. can you post the explain plan for the query?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want "yesterday", the logic would be:

```
select *
from inventory_transaction
where Complete_timestamp >= trunc(sysdate - 1) and
      Complete_timestamp < trunc(sysdate);
```

What is important here is the `trunc()` so you get calendar days.  Otherwise, you have the *time* in the comparison.  Despite its name, `sysdate` has a time component.

I would also use `sysdate - interval '1' day`, but that has no impact on performance or results.

Why is this slow?  There could be multiple reasons.  The most likely is that `inventory_transaction` is a table.  In that case, you want an index on `inventory_transaction(complete_timestamp)`.

Another possibility is that there is a lot of data.  More data takes more time for the database to read.  There is no way around that, other than upgrading the server or changing server parameters (if they are suboptimal).

Another possibility is that `inventory_transaction` is really a view.  If that is the case, you need to optimize the view.  It is possible that an index on an underlying column will speed the query.  However, it might be the entire view that needs to be optimized.